# Which drive's MBR does the Windows 7 installer overwrite?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, mbr

Is it the first drive listed? Or is it the drive the `C:\` partition belongs to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows will install a master boot record on the first physical disk (`\device\harddisk0`). This may or may not correspond to the disk which contains the `C:\` volume or the Windows system volume.

Comment: Thanks...but I believe that while your part is certainly relevant, the question was rather "where the MBR will be installed". Maybe you would like to elaborate a little on this? :)

Comment: @Alois Mahdal Most often the fist physical disk.

Comment: @AloisMahdal What's there to elaborate on? I've edited it so my meaning is clearer.

Comment: @Amazed Oh, now I get it. The edit fixed it. No further elaboration is necessary :) Thanks!

Comment: I am positive that the device the machine is set to boot from (the drive I installed to) was not listed as device 0. But it loads up just fine.